# How to encode message into image

Tags: c++, image, ppm

I have a school project I've been working on for awhile now. It is supposed to encode a message into an image via red pixel values.

It should work like this: set pixels red value equal to the first ascii character value in message. Then, set the pixels green value to an x and blue value to a y that gives the coordinates of the next pixel that contains the next letter in the message. This then loops until the last value, at which point it sets the green and blue values to 0, to mark the end of the message.

I've been able to decode the sample images I have, but after running my following encode file on a new image, it only decodes the very last letter in the message.

```
#ifndef ENCODE
#define ENCODE

#include "ImageEffect.h"
#include "time.h"

//this image effect will encode an image
class Encode : public ImageEffect
{
    virtual void processImage(PpmDocument &doc)
    {
        {
            int x = 2, y = 2;
            Pixel& p = doc.getPixel(0, 0);
            srand(time(NULL));

            p.setGreen(x);
            p.setBlue(y);

            string message = "test message";
            p.setRed((int)message[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < message.size(); i++)
            {
                p.setRed((int)message[i]);
                x += (rand() % 3) + 1;
                y += (rand() % 3) + 1;
                p.setGreen(x);
                p.setBlue(y);
                Pixel& p = doc.getPixel(x, y);
            }
            p.setGreen(0);
            p.setBlue(0);
        }
    }
};

#endif // !ENCODE
```

So, when I run this, and then run my decoder, it spits out an 'e' and ends.

Comment: Turn on warnings ? that second `Pixel& p = doc.getPixel(x, y);` should definitely have given you a warning about shadowing an earlier p (and maybe you would have got a warning about an unused `p` as well). [Edit: actually, -Wall and -Wextra don't seem to turn on -Wshadow on my versions of clang and g++, that's sad :( ]

Comment: Looks like you write to your first and to your last pixel twice

Comment: What if the issue is in the decoder? We can't see that.